# mod_rewrite - all to index except static folder

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying and trying and can't find the solution, which surely is pretty easy. I have rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

So it redirects all urls to index.php, now I want all files expect this in static folder to be redirected, so urls like domain.com/static/... would not be redirected. I tried for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^static$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule static/(.*) static/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

And some other variations but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Your last ruleset looks correct to me did you try [R,L] instead of [L]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex, use a negative look-ahead

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/static/).+ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tested it on a IIS server with an ISAPI plugin for mod_rewrite.  It's supposed to be the same as apache's syntax.  If it's no good for you, try without the slash in front of "static".  If still no good, I'll retract my answer :-(

Comment: Oh, and regardless of whether my rewrite rule works, I'm pretty sure your server hates you.

Comment: Ok, it works:D The only thing which bothers me, when this file in static folder exists it works, but if not it redirects to index.php. I thought in non-existsing file case should be 404 or something...