# Javascript Client Routing - Reload Page

Tags: javascript, url-routing, single-page-application

I have a client side router with which I can navigate through my web application with hash based urls, like `http://example.com/#home`. With the `history.pushState(..)` method I make the url more cleaner, like `http://example.com/home`. Now my problem is when someone reload the page, the url is unknown, because there is no hash in it. Is there a elegant way to fix this?

Comment: Is it to late to use angularjs with stateProvider in your webapp?

Comment: I want to implement that without any additional framework.

Comment: I think the only possible solution is handle this routes on the server and perform a redirect to your spa main page with a hashed url and then do a history.pushState again

Answer (score 3):

**What it's meant for**

`history.pushState(..)` is needed for single-page-applications to create an artificial browser history. That artificial history allows users to navigate via back and forward buttons and also to bookmark a "page" (there is only one, but it feels like multiple pages).

**What you're doing**

Now you're rewriting URLs to locations, which don't exist. On reload the browser navigates to that location and finds nothing, it doesn't know the relationship between your single-page-application and that new URL.

**Solutions**

1. You could try to fix this by creating redirections on server-side. Then you'll be able to [read the current state](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Reading_the_current_state). There are multiple options for redirects:

   - [mod_rewrite - all to index except static folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7502682/199048)
   - [Redirect from an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5411538/199048) (discouraged)
   - ...
2. Keep the hashed URLs and use the saved time to work on real features.

I'd take the second option.

Comment: You are right. Number two seems to be the better way.